# Setup shadedrelief background in basemap using a cropped orthographic projection

Tags: python, coordinate-system, basemap, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a sector of the world in basemap using an orthographic projection and I would like to have a shadedrelief background.

If I don't use shadedrelief everything works fine:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

m = Basemap(projection='ortho',lon_0 = 0, lat_0 = 40,
        llcrnrx=-3000000, llcrnry=1000000, urcrnrx=3000000, urcrnry=7000000, 
        resolution = 'l')

m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')

# draw parallels and meridians.
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,120.,30.))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0.,420.,60.))
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
```

[image: Orthographic projection without shadedrelief background]

However, when I add the command `m.shadedrelief()` (after removing the `m.drawmapboundary` and the `m.fillcontinents` commands) I get the following graph:
[image: Orthographic projection with shadedrelief background]

Apparently the problem is that the background is not restricted to the bounding box I set in the basemap command. I tried also with other backgrounds (e.g. bluemarble) but they have the same problem.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I searched online but I didn't found anything unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue.

my only answer is : get the data from return of bluemarble and crop the data array

im = basemap.bluemarble()
data = im.get_array()

modify the data to make it correspond to your need and push it back to the image

im.set_array(new_data)